# Getting error unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 app. I am getting the same error as mentioned in the below SO link.

[Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678571/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-path-line-1-positio)

The solution suggested in the answer section seems to solve the issue as well.

But creating a class for one property is overhead & doesn't appeal to me.

In the past, I did the same without creating such overhead class with .Net Framework 4.5(+)

```cs
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string email)
{
}
```

Through Postman, I POST

```
{
    "email": "myemail@email.com"
}
```

How can I pass the email value to API without creating any class or
 such?

I would prefer to stick `[FromBody]`, as all the APIs in my application is accepting the params `FromBody` in `Post` method.

Comment: That's an object with an `email` property, not a string. Either remove `{}` or accept an object with an email property on the server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to pass the email value without creating class, just pass

```
"myemail@email.com"
```

without the `{}` brackets and the `email` key. When you pass

```
{
"email": "myemail@email.com"
}
```

the parser correctly suggests that this value represents object with property `email`, that is why wrapper class is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you're *only ever* going to need *one argument*, then go ahead and make it a string, as others have suggested. But please remember that you will not be able to receive two arguments from the body in ASP.NET Core: you will have to define a type that contains two (or more) properties, and the single object in the request body will be mapped to that type. So, if you're not sure, **just save yourself the future refactoring and define a type for your request**.

**Don't be afraid of creating one more class in your project.** It is a very small overhead for the machine, and a minuscule annoyance for you to spend three minutes writing it, but it improves the quality of your code, makes it more expressive, and it can even help you by making the compiler find mistakes you may not have noticed. Just **give it a meaningful name**, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put in a string without the key, the api will still accept it:

```
"myemail@email.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call `JSON.stringify(email)` to pass the email to the api, and also the content type as a header.  This is how I solved the issue:

```
post(id: number, email: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
    const url = this.baseUrl + `api/Portfolio/InviteUser/${id}`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, JSON.stringify(email), httpOptions);
  }
```

My Web Api also contained an Id in the URI:

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> InviteUser(int id, [FromBody] string email)
```